# Align child to the right side of parent div like an chat app

Tags: css

I have 3 div, I want the 2nd div to be on the right just like a chat app. How can I achieve that with standard CSS or bootstrap. I have tried pull-right but it just messes up the layout by shifting the 3rd div up and 2nd div to top right.

```
<div>div1</div>
<div class="pull-right">div2</div>
<div>div3</div>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

by using bootstrap you can achieve this

```css
.child{border:2px solid #000; height:200px; margin:5px 0; min-width:100px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 child pull-left"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 child pull-right"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 child pull-left"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```